# determining a and b so the function becomes differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $\begin{eqnarray}
> f(x)= \begin{cases} x^3+ax^2+b&\quad\text {if } x \le 1 \cr 
> 2x+3&\quad\text{if } x \ge 1\cr \end{cases} 
> \end{eqnarray}$
>
> **a)** Determine $a$ and $b$ so that $f$ is differentiable at 1.
>
> **b)** Is $f$ differentiable twice at 1 after determining $a$ and $b$?

My work:

For the continuity, I got $a=4-b$, but for the differential I cant get a decent result when coming from $-$ ($2x+3$ I got to 2, as should)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Once $2x+3$ is a line, if you want $f$ to be differentiable at $1$ then $2x+3$ must to be tangent to $x^3+ax^2+b$ at $1$, so:

$$f'(x)=(x^3+ax^2+b)'=3x^2+2ax=(2x+3)'=2\\
 f'(1)=2=3+2a \rightarrow a=-\frac{1}{2}$$

That give us $b=4-a=\frac{9}{2}$.

Can you finish?

Comment: @repulsive23: is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier, you will realise that you can differentiate $f(x)$ to eliminate $b$.

Determine the derivative $f'(x)$:

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases} 3x^2+2ax&\quad\text {if } x \le 1 \cr 
2&\quad\text{if } x \ge 1\cr \end{cases}$$

Thus, you can evaluate limits $x\to 1$ on both sides and set them equal.

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} (3x^2+2ax)=\lim_{x\to 1^+} (2)$$

$$3+2a=2$$

Thus,

$$\boxed{a=-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Now, you can use this to find $b$ on $f(x)$ so that your function becomes continuous.

$$
f(x)= \begin{cases} x^3-\frac{1}{2}x^2+b&\quad\text {if } x \le 1 \cr 
2x+3&\quad\text{if } x \ge 1\cr \end{cases} $$

Evaluate limits:

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}(x^3-\frac{1}{2}x^2+b)=\lim_{x\to 1^+}(2x+3)$$

$$1-\frac{1}{2}+b=5$$

$$\boxed{b=\frac{9}{2}}$$

For part **(b)**, just differentiate $f(x)$ twice to obtain $f''(x)$ and evaluate limits, and check whether they are equal or not. If you want, you can comment on the answer you get for part **(b)**.